# Selet de todos os registro de um clausula IN em Mysql

Tags: mysql, where

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês pois fiz um consulta simples que precisaria retorno todos os registro especificados na cláusula IN . Nesta cláusula IN (  TF.CodTreina IN ) esta vindo de um select. O problema é que esta retornando alguns funcionários que tenha alguns treinamentos. O que preciso é apresentar somente os funcionários que tenha dos os treinamentos especificados na cláusula IN. O Detalhe é o funcionário não pode ser da área que será vinda do filtro, por exemplo código da área 1, porque quero mostrar os substitutos.

```
SELECT 
  FA.MatriculaSese, 
  TF.CodTreina,
  TF.Data,
  TF.Status, 
  FA.CentroCusto 
FROM treina_func TF 
INNER JOIN func_area FA 
  ON TF.MatriculaSese = FA.MatriculaSese 
WHERE FA.CentroCusto <> 1 
  AND TF.CodTreina IN (
    SELECT TA.CodTreina FROM treina_area TA WHERE TA.CodArea = 1 
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentando explicar melhor.O problema esta sendo é que gostaria  que no select retorna somente  os funcionários que tenha  todos os treinamento da clausula IN. Os código do treinamento da area 1 são IN( 1,16,32,64,122,136,168,169,170,171, 198, 199) gostaria que no select retornasse  todos os funcionários que tenha exatamente  todos estes treinamento. No código informado esta retornando funcionários que tenha um o outro e não todos. Existe algo que retornasse somente os funcionários que tenha todos os treinamento na clausula IN?

Senhores refazendo e minha duvida acho que agora vai ficar mais claro

```
   SELECT * FROM vw_treina_func TF WHERE TF.CodTreina IN (1,16,22,33,75,97,110,115,158,161,164,173)
```

Gostaria que este select so mostrasse os funcionários que tenham todos estes treinamentos e não um outro como esta acontecendo.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. O que exatamente você quer atingir? Poderia dar um exemplo dos dados contidos em cada tabela e do resultado esperado?

Comment: Também não entendi, tentei editar a pergunta mas não dei conta. Me perdi.

Comment: "...o funcionário não pode ser da área que será vinda do filtro, por exemplo código da área 1..."
Ta bem confuso mesmo, mas pelo que entendi acima, basta trocar para NOT IN.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann eu acho que os substitudos dos funcionarios da área 1 não são os efetivos das outras areas, por isso o `NOT IN` não funcionária. Penso que teria de ser algo assim: `IN( SELECT TA.CodTreina FROM treina_area TA WHERE TA.CodArea = 1 AND SUBSTITUTO = 1 )`

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo faz todo sentido mesmo, mas vamos ter que aguardar ele editar pra saber oque ele realmente precisa. rs

Comment: A tabela treina_area contem todos os treinamento que um funcionário tem que ter para trabalhar nas area da empresa. A tabela treina_func registra todos os treinamento que o funcionário tem. O que eu estou precisando agora é saber os funcionários que tem todos os treinamento da area 1 por isto: TF.CodTreina IN só que o funcionário não pode ser efetivo da área 1 porque esta consulta tem que mostrar os funcionários de outras que pode substituir um dos funcionários efetivo da area 1. Vou tentar inserir a imagem que é gerada da relação funcionário x treinamento X area.

Comment: Acabei de adiciona a relação dos funcionários da área 1 com os devidos treinamento referente a área 1. este são os funcionários efetivo da area. A minha dificuldade e do select para mostra os  funcionários que também tenha todos estes 12 treinamento mas que não seja desta área 1.

Comment: Ninguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Alguém?  So preciso que o resultado me traga todos os funcionarios que tenha dentro da clausula IN . Infezlimente o IN traz um o outro e não todos ?

Comment: consegui resolver a questão pois comparando arrays.